# Excel: Dynamic referencing

Tags: excel, dynamic, reference

I'm struggling with this formula

`="'[workbook.xlsx]"&INDIRECT(B1)&"'!"&$C$5`

B1 is a date: 05-09-22 and is also the name of a sheet in workbook.xlsx

What am I doing wrong?

Thanx for looking,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula.

```
=INDIRECT("'[workbook.xlsm]" & B1 &"'!$C$5")
```